# javascript preview image before upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a code in the img box in sequence. However, if the if (file.size > 1M) is large, a space occurs in the img box.
How do I get the next image to come in without spaces?

**

> javascript preview image before upload

**

```
<form class="my_form">
<input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" 
onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<label class="button" for="fileElem">Select Images</label>
<div id="gallery">
<img id="**imgg0**" class="imgg">
<img id="**imgg1**" class="imgg">
<img id="**imgg2**" class="imgg">
<img id="**imgg3**" class="imgg">
<img id="**imgg4**" class="imgg">
</div>               
</form>
<script>
function handleFiles(files) {
var files = [...files]
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
files.forEach(function(file, index){
if(file.size > 1000000){
delete file[index];
} else{ 
let reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
reader.onloadend = function() {
var img = **document.getElementById('imgg'+index)**;
img.src = reader.result;  
}
} 
})
}
</script>
[enter image description here][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dJ45.png
```

Comment: isn't it possible to get file name and set img src as that file name ? so with a client side logic you will be previewing image to user from his computer then when he clicks on upload. it will be uploaded ?

Comment: Before upload, I want to implement preview only.
I just want to show the following image in the preview blank.

Comment: okay its what i am saying so aren't you able to get FileName method to get file path in client ? so put img src as FileName.

Comment: The path cannot be obtained by file name before upload.

Answer (score 1):

Check my solution.

```js
function handleFiles(files) {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    //Image element undex
    let imgIndex=0;

    //Loop through all the images
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var img = document.getElementById('imgg'+imgIndex);
          img.src = e.target.result; 
          imgIndex++;
        }
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);     
   }
}
```

```html
<form class="my_form">
 <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
 <label class="button" for="fileElem">Select Images</label>
 <div id="gallery">
  <img id="imgg0" width="10%" class="imgg">
  <img id="imgg1" width="10%" class="imgg">
  <img id="imgg2" width="10%" class="imgg">
  <img id="imgg3" width="10%" class="imgg">
  <img id="imgg4" width="10%" class="imgg">
 </div>               
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution for multi-image previews. This creates img placeholders dynamically for as many pictures selected in file control

```
<div id="container01"></div>
<input id="filer" type="file" onchange="preview()" multiple="multiple" />

<script>
    function preview() {
        var element = document.getElementById("container01");
        for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
            var imgi = document.createElement('img'); // variable imgi has i loop counter   
            imgi.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
            imgi.style.width = "100px";
            imgi.style.height = "100px";
            element.appendChild(imgi); // add new preview to container

            var space = document.createTextNode(" "); // spacer between imgs
            element.appendChild(space); // add space for horizontal preview
//          var linebreak = document.createElement('br'); // add line break <br/>   
//          element.appendChild(linebreak);
            
            
        }
    }
</script>
```